# Can I query a secondary index for a list of values in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

Can I query a secondary index for a list of values in DynamoDB?

Partition key: accountId

Sort Key: fieldId

I want to query fieldId for a list of values.

```
.withKeyCondition(
S(“accountId”).eq(accountId)
.and(S(“fieldId”).in(“companyType”, “companyName”, “firstName”, “lastName”))
)
```

What is the recommended table structure for this use-case?

Comment: Please tell us which attributes you are using for your partition key and sort key.

Comment: @F_SO_K added required information.